# java -version In Bash Script. Giving integer error

Tags: linux, scripting, java, test

I am trying to make this `if..fi` case work for the Java Version from `wrapper.conf` configuration file./ and from the system, If the output from `wrapper.conf` is `java`

I would have two options;
1. wrapper.java.command=/apps/jdk1.8.0_191/bin/java
2. wrapper.java.command=java

If it's long one with Java Version it should just print it.

If it's just java, which means it's using default java, and should check the java -version.

With Below script, I am failing to get it. I am getting below error.

```
integer expression expected
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

Script Snippet:

```
for file in $(echo $folder/conf/wrapper.conf)

do

JavaVersion=$(grep "command" $file | awk -F "=" '{print $NF}')

if [ "$JavaVersion" -eq "java" ]; then

java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version'

else

$JavaVersion

fi
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! It looks like a final `done` is missing in your snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the [missing `done` for your loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484702/getting-java-version-in-bash-script-with-if-fi-statement#comment888421_484702) that fra-san commented on and the `-eq` *integer comparison* complaining about the strings you asked it to compare, there's also the error where you called some particular java binary with no parameters, generating the second half of the error you saw.

Since you're likely wanting the java version in either case, simply execute `$JavaVersion` regardless.

```
JavaVersion=$(grep wrapper.java.command= "$file" | awk -F "=" '{print $NF}')
"$JavaVersion" -version
```

Appears I misunderstood the end goal of printing the wrapper.java.command value if it's not exactly `java`, otherwise executing `java -version`.

```
if grep -Fxq wrapper.java.command=java "$file" 
then
  java -version 2>&1 | grep 'java version'
else
  grep ^wrapper.java.command= "$file" | cut -d= -f2-
fi
```

Comment: Hey Jeff Schaller, Thank you for the Answer. I have the other "done" at the end of the script. Since it's big script, I just took one snipped from it. 

Can you please explain what this will do here?  

"$JavaVersion" -version

Comment: It'll run whatever you found in the file as the wrapper.java.command and add the `-version` option.I put quotes around it in case someone decided to package a "/usr/bin/java funny version with spaces"

Comment: I need to run java -version and get the Default Java Version from the system. What would be best way to get it?

Comment: run `java -version`? I'm not sure what "Default Java Version" is in this situation. Perhaps it's worth a separate question?

Comment: Actually this is my Main Concern here :) I need to get java -version from the system, if the output from wrapper.conf is "java" if long text, then just print.

Comment: Appears I misunderstood; see the recent edit.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You can check below comments with Jesse_b, I am struggling to get the Output from java -version command. It's throwing integer error.

Comment: The commands I'm suggesting shouldn't produce an integer error. I see you're just looking for the version line, so I'll update my Answer to grep for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `-eq` operator is for integer comparison.  Since you are trying to compare strings you will need to use `=`, specifically:

```
if [ "$JavaVersion" = "java" ]; then
```

---

Additionally, the following line seems flawed:

```
java -version 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep 'java version'
```

You are redirecting both stdout and stderr to /dev/null (all output) so there will be nothing left to grep.

Comment: Thank you for your input. 

I have modified "-eq" to "=" operator. Regarding the Java Command, I can get the output on the command line. What do you suggest me to replace it with?

Comment: @Bek I suggest removing the redirects.  So just: `java -version | grep 'java version'`

Comment: java -version |grep 'java version' is giving me every single text it has. I can't even filter it with awk. Have you tested it? Not working for me thou.

Comment: I have tested with   -   java -version | grep 'java version'   - 
And still giving the same Integer error

Comment: `java -version` outputs the text to stderr

Comment: In the case that it outputs to stderr then you should do: `java -version 2>&1 | grep 'java version'` or `'java -version |& grep 'java version'`

Comment: with this option, I am still getting the "Usage: Java issue " 
java -version 2>&1 | grep 'java version'